# Is there a "print to file" parameter or its equivalent for bitcoin-cli; so that results from the daemon are recorded

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

Is there any way to "print to file" the queried results of the bitcoin-cli. This would be most helpful in my basic cross platform integration of a program I am making with QB64.

Comment: Can't you just redirect the output to a file? `bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo > out.txt`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really about programming in a variant of Quick-Basic, specifically how in QuickBasic to capture the STDOUT of an external program run in a `shell` statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41305926/how-to-pipe-stdout-and-stdin-to-qbasic-program.